# prevent page reload after redirect

Tags: javascript

I am able to redirect/replace the url from the below code

```js
function replceUrl(){
  window.location.assign("https://www.example.com");
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

After replacing the url, I want to stop page reload. I have added `event.preventDefault()`, but the page still reloads.

How to prevent page reload after replacing the url is the challenge

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I modify the URL without reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-do-i-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: can you explain your problem better?

Comment: after this - window.location.assign... in my code, the page reloads, I want to prevent that

Answer (score 0):

`event.preventDefault()` won't help you there, its purpose is to prevent the default behavior of the event that fired the function.

You won't be able to change the URL without reloading the page unless you use [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) or `window.location.hash`

[History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) will let you change the last URL segment without reloading the page with this code: `history.pushState({some: 'data'}, "New title", "new-url-segment")` while `window.location.hash = 'something'` will let you change the [URL fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/hash).

Note that the URL fragment's original purpose is to create links that scrolls to a specific `id` in the page once it's loaded.

Comment: so can u modify the answer using the history api as suggested

Comment: this approach does not over write the url completely, I do not just want to over write the url fragment

Comment: @Blaze Have you even gone through any answer in the suggested duplicate?

Comment: sure and its same with Guerric answer, u can extract from ur suggestion and post here, please

Comment: Yes, but it's the best thing you can do, you won't be able to manually change the full URL without reloading the page, and you won't be able to do it programmatically either. Imagine you could impersonate google.com by copying their website, hosting it on your own domain, then changing the URL with JavaScript!